# Loop yearmonthdate folders in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

`I have Year Month Date folders in blob storage like Year(Months(Dates)), 2020(04(01),(02),(03),...,(30))
(05(01),(02),(03),...,(31))
(06(01),(02),(03),...,(30))
I want to loop through these folders and load into SQL table. How can we do in Azure Data Factory?

```
 I tried get metadata---->For each----Copy activity (here is the question like in copy activity how to 
 give filename dynamically?)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parameter of Source DataSet in Copy Data activity, and then pass the pass the file name to the parameter with this expression(`@item().name`) in Copy Data activity.